# Why does mist throw 'Uncaught invalid address'?

Tags: web3js, mist, addresses, dapp-development, contract-invocation

I'm trying to make a web page that gets a message from a simple "hello world" smart contract. Unfortunately, it isn't working. I'm seeing this in the Mist console.

```
Uncaught invalid address
v                     @ web3.min.js:2
p                     @ web3.min.js:2
(anonymous function)  @ web3.min.js:2
i.formatInput         @ web3.min.js:2
i.toPayload           @ web3.min.js:2
i.buildCall.e         @ web3.min.js:2
s.sendTransaction     @ web3.min.js:2
s.execute             @ web3.min.js:2
(anonymous function)  @ (index):26
```

The web page is [here](http://sinking-point.github.io/ethelloworld) and the contract source code is [here](https://github.com/sinking-point/ethelloworld/blob/master/source.txt). I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 9):

This error appears when you do not have a defaultAccount property set in the web3.eth object.
Try to execute this in Javascript console:

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount=web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

(assuming you have some accounts created already)

Comment: I've just tried that. I get:

`Error: Provider not set or invalid at Object.e.exports.InvalidProvider...`

and

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at <anonymous>:2:42...`

Comment: How could you achieve this without explicitly setting the defaultAccount?

Comment: This one worked for me.

Comment: Mist 9.0 `Uncaught Error: No callback given, sync calls are not possible anymore in Mist. Please use only async calls.`

Answer (score 2):

According to your error, you are yet to set up the provider.

`web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8102'));`

where localhost and port refers to the ethereum server node you intend use with the Web3.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Alexey, the error happens because of undefined defaultAccount property.

The work around for it in javascript is adding the below statement

```
web3.eth.defaultAccount = ethereum._state.accounts[0]
```

Here we have used `ethereum._state.accounts[0]` instead of `web3.eth.accounts[0]` since it is deprecated to be used by metamask as documented in the website

https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#summary-of-breaking-changes

Answer (score 0):

From:  https://github.com/jefflau/ens-manager/issues/36

New sync calls are not permitted on the newest versions of web3.js. As a result, the app will not detect the correct user and therefore not allow you to manage it and log an error:

Uncaught (in promise) Error: No callback given, sync calls are not possible anymore in Mist. Please use only async calls.

You should replace all

```
web3.eth.accounts[0]
```

with:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(e,accounts){ // do something });
```